# Docker Image not starting up correctly

Tags: java, mysql, docker, tomcat, camunda

I am trying to run an image from Camunda workflow engine.

I used the source code from here:
https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform

I changed the Driver and the connection to:

```
ENV DB_DRIVER=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
ENV DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://xxx.mysql.database.azure.com/camunda;MVCC=TRUE;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
ENV DB_USERNAME=xxx@mysqlserverforcamunda
ENV DB_PASSWORD=xxxx.
```

the docker build commmands works perfect.

However, if I run docker run:

```
docker run -d --name camunda2 -p 8080:8080 -e SKIP_DB_CONFIG=true openjdk:8u191-jre-alpine3.9
```

Note:  I have created all the tables in advance in mysql already, thats why I added the SKIP DB CONFIG flag

THere is nothing in the logs:

```
docker logs -f cbcdef0df5a5abe7f9b144e14e04996932696aeca9835f48adcc48854dcf11f8
```

Question: How can I troubleshoot whats going on? what the real error is.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to run the container in the foreground for debugging and troubleshooting purpose.

```
docker run -it --name camunda2 -p 8080:8080 -e SKIP_DB_CONFIG=true openjdk:8u191-jre-alpine3.9
```

Also will suggest checking logs of this specific container using the container name or ID of the container.

```
docker logs -f camunda2
```

**Debug**

> To enable JPDA inside the container you can set the environment
>   variable `DEBUG=true` on startup of the container. This will allow you
>   to connect to the container on port 8000 to debug your application.

[ocker-camunda-bpm-platform-debug](https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform#debug)

**update:**

You need to run `camunda/camunda-bpm-platform`, while you are running `openjdk:8u191-jre-alpine3.9` and there is nothing to expose and the image provide just JDK platform so it will exist or it will enter to shell if you run it in the foreground.

```
 docker run --rm -it --name camunda -p 8080:8080 camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:latest
```

Comment: docker logs with the container name, gives no results

Comment: try to run with `DEBUG=true`

Comment: done, rebuilt the image, re-run the container, exits inmediately, if I try to go to localhost:8000, well, its down...

Comment: Run in foreground

Comment: With - it instead of - d

Comment: ok, the container is up, now I am in the container Shell, localhost:8000 does not work, what can I do to troubleshoot here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198991/discussion-between-luis-valencia-and-adiii).